# Elasticsearch & NetFlix Edda - NoNodeAvailableException: No node available

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I am trying to get [Netflix open source solution Edda](https://github.com/Netflix/edda/wiki/Quick-Start-Guide) to work with Elasticsearch.  I know I've installed Edda correctly because I can get it working with MongoDB as a backend successfully.  I'd prefer to use Elasticsearch so I can get the benefits of Kibana rather than write my own frontend.  So I'm running Edda and Elasticsearch on the same server in AWS at the moment (just trying to get it working).  Elasticsearch is operational:

```
{
  "name" : "Arsenic",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "2.1.0",
    "build_hash" : "72cd1f1a3eee09505e036106146dc1949dc5dc87",
    "build_timestamp" : "2015-11-18T22:40:03Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "5.3.1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

And to show it's listening:

```
netstat -tulpn | grep java
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:<myip>:9300    :::*                        LISTEN      2270/java
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:<myip>:9200    :::*                        LISTEN      2270/java
```

My java version I updated from 1.7 to 1.8 as I believe the java version for Elasticsearch and what is running on the server have to match.  I can't see a reason why 1.8 would be causing an issue:

```
java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_65"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_65-b17)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.65-b01, mixed mode)
```

Here's my edda properties file:

```
cat /home/ec2-user/edda/src/main/resources/edda.properties | grep elasticsearch
edda.datastore.current.class=com.netflix.edda.elasticsearch.ElasticSearchDatastore
edda.elector.class=com.netflix.edda.elasticsearch.ElasticSearchElector
edda.elasticsearch.cluster=elasticsearch
edda.elasticsearch.address=<myip>:9300
edda.elasticsearch.shards=5
edda.elasticsearch.replicas=0
# http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/index_/
edda.elasticsearch.writeConsistency=quorum
edda.elasticsearch.replicationType=async
edda.elasticsearch.scanBatchSize=1000
edda.elasticsearch.scanCursorDuration=60000
edda.elasticsearch.bulkBatchSize=0
```

And in my elasticsearch.yml file:

```
network.host: <myip>
```

I haven't specified a clustername so it assumes the default 'elasticseach'.

So when I run Edda to poll AWS and populate elasticsearch with the data it finds I receive this error:

```
[Collection aws.hostedZones] init: caught org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: No node available
        at com.netflix.edda.Collection$$anonfun$init$1.apply$mcV$sp(Collection.scala:471)
        at com.netflix.edda.Utils$$anon$1.act(Utils.scala:169)
        at scala.actors.Reactor$$anonfun$dostart$1.apply(Reactor.scala:224)
        at scala.actors.Reactor$$anonfun$dostart$1.apply(Reactor.scala:224)
        at scala.actors.ReactorTask.run(ReactorTask.scala:33)
        at scala.actors.ReactorTask.compute(ReactorTask.scala:63)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.RecursiveAction.exec(RecursiveAction.java:160)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

Clearly it can't connect to the elasticsearch cluster yet the cluster name is correct, it's listening on the correct port and ip address as far as I can tell and I don't think there's an issue with the java version.

I'm missing something probably very simple.

Thanks in advance for all your assistance.

Regards
Neilos

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out, the java client used in Edda is set to use version 0.90.0 of elasticsearch which is set in build.gradle, if you install that version of Elasticsearch it works.  Obviously that's a very old version of Elasticsearch which you are not likely to want to use.  If you change the version number in this file it fails when it tries to compile due to broken paths (missing assemblies).  I'm weighing up whether it's worth trying to resolve these assembly issues to get it working with the latest version of Elasticsearch or choose to use MongoDB which works without any code changes but will only provide REST Api functionality.  At least the problem is resolved.